# Can I disable the rebalancing of disks in Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-server, storage-spaces

I want to disable the "Optimize" and "Repair" jobs that automatically run after new disks are added to the pool. I have been trying to google the solution and scanning Windows' storage related powershell commands, but haven't found any solution. Is there way to accomplish this?

I am using Windows server 2016.

[Note: I understand the implications of doing this.]

Answer (score 0):

The closest I think you can come to this is to disable Storage Spaces retiring
of a missing disk and so automatically starting a repair.

Use the PowerShell command
[Set-StoragePool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-storagepool?view=win10-ps)
with the parameters `-RetireMissingPhysicalDisks Never`, described as:

> When set to Never, Windows never retires missing physical disks.

This is one step in the recommended procedure when replacing a bad disk,
as described in
[Turn off automatic disk retirement in the storage pool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn782852(v%3Dws.11)#step-2-turn-off-automatic-disk-retirement-in-the-storage-pool).